# How can I get my sink's trap to fit around the rest of the drain assembly?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, drainage

I'm in the process of adding a new bathroom to my house.  I had a plumber rough in some connections for us, and then we are in the process of finishing it off.  We used plastic accordion pipe to connect the P-trap to the sink, but during our county inspection they failed us saying that the accordion was something we could use because its a known area that hair gets caught in.  The drain from the sink is brass as is the P-trap.  We can't S-trap trap because they are not allowed per code either.  Does anyone know what we can do?

[image: Sink Connection]
[image: Side image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the drain exit from that photo, but I recently resolved this exact issue at my home by installing a slight bend in the horizontal run from the wall (with a 22-1/2 or 30 degree ell), which offsets the connection to the trap. This allows standard trap components to be used.

Comment: Done the same here you may want to cut the down pipe from the sink shorter to provide a little more room for pulling the trap at a later time when it is full of hair.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the code rules but if you screw two 90 degree elbows together where you have the accordion, you should able to get things to come together roughly where the p-trap connects now.  You might need a slip-joint and a bit of straight drain.

I don't believe this is an S-trap since you are not going up and down again.  I'd be interested if anyone knows a problem with this approach or if it's an inspection issue.

One note on slip joints: make sure you have the right ring.  I like to buy the hard rubber ones that are red.  The rubber or plastic should be triangular so that it wedges in as you tighten.  If you can move it after you've tightened it, you did something wrong and it won't hold water.

Comment: I had the same though, but thought it would be a touch more aesthetically pleasing to put the bends in back. I suppose it's up to the owner.

Comment: @isherwood Both are viable.  Trying to get the waste out can be a pain in an old house, though.  I had to cut up the waste pipe and chisel out the lead that held it in the threads with a screwdriver.  I was about to curse the guy the told me to do this after banging on it for what seemed like hours and then it finally started curling up for me.  Since this is all new, that shouldn't be an issue.